# After div disabled, change to disabled color or css of its contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have button and Image in `<div>`. When I made `<div>` to disable. Its content is not graying out like disable. I can still same thing like enable.

How to change div content background to disable color (transparent)?

```
<div style="display:inline-block" id="divImgAddOrUpdate" >  
   <button id="imgAddOrUpdate" type="submit" class="btn"  >
            <img src="Images/save.png" alt="" />Add/Update
   </button>
</div>
```

### JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         $('#divImgAddOrUpdate').prop('disabled', true);
         $('#divImgAddOrUpdate *').prop('disabled', true);
</script>
```

### css

```
 .btn {      

    border:.1em #868686 solid; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family:Segoe UI; 
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 5px; 
    text-decoration:none; 
    display:inline-block;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    text-align:left;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #f4f5f5; 
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f4f5f5, #dfdddd);
 }
.btn:hover{
    border:1px solid #bfc4c4;
    background-color: #d9dddd; background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #d9dddd, #c6c3c3);
}
.btn img {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7nBjV/2/)

Comment: disable the div todo what?

Comment: There is no `disabled` property for `div` elements (or any others except interactive form-elements, `input`, `textarea`, `select` etc).

Comment: $('#divImgAddOrUpdate').prop('disabled', 'disabled');

Comment: @jp310: `disabled` (outside of XHTML) is a Boolean attribute: it's either there or it isn't, it doesn't require a value.

Comment: Why don't you just add another class to the div? E.g.:
$('#divImgAddOrUpdate').addClass("div-disabled");
As mentioned by David the disabled attribute is only valid on form elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the `:disabled` pseudo-class and `:not` pseudo-class like this:

```
/* this is edited from your original style */
.btn:not(:disabled):hover{
    border:1px solid #bfc4c4;
    background-color: #d9dddd; background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #d9dddd, #c6c3c3);
}
/* this is added */
.btn:disabled {
   color:grey;
   background-color:gray;
}
/* style for graying out the img */
.btn:disabled > img {    
   filter:gray;
   -webkit-filter:grayscale(100%);
   -moz-filter:grayscale(100%);    
   filter:grayscale(100%);
}
```

Here is the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7nBjV/3/)

Comment: thanks for your code. Is it possible to with image (inside button) gray out?

Comment: @James123 I updated the code as well as the fiddle for graying out the image.